# Plugins not showing up for custom template

Tags: css, javascript, html5

I'm customizing the `index.php` page. I've customized my `header.php` and `footer.php` and created the styles for both things.

My main `index.php` page has:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Main
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

Coming soon!

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried to install a plugin called sticky footer. It's purpose is to keep the footer at the bottom of the page and NOT overlapping my content when resizing the browser. I can't get that plugin to work. So if you can advise me on how I could go about getting the plugin to work or know of a way to keep my footer from overlapping my content when resizing yet remaining at the bottom, I'd really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Always Put wp_head() in header and wp_footer() in footer. the plugin uses this hook

**Header.php:**

```
 <?php 
     ...
        /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
         * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
         * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
         * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
         */
        wp_head();
     ?>
     </head>
```

**Footer.php:**

```
<?php
   /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
    * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
    * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
    */
    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those things are already there in the header.php and footer.php